# Angular 2 - moving from local to test env

Tags: node.js, angular

I just created a small Angular 2 page which retrieves
data from SQL DB and display them in a table. All good here..
I deployed that from my local machine to a test environments ( we have many ).
We use Bamboo to deploy..

But when I run my page, it says it's not able to find 
any of node modules - essentially it just hangs
on "loading app". On F12 I see 404s for all *app/node-modules/system.js* files, etc..

Just to mention I did not run an npm install 
on my new environment after deployment since the node modules are all present in my package ( I am new to node and Angular 2)

Please, let me know what am I missing. The page works just fine on local machine.

Comment: Your package.json just maintains a record of the packages and versions you depend on. It definitely doesn't actually include the modules themselves. You'll need to run NPM install on your deployed environment. This is usually done as part of the build process. A quick google turned up this result: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboocloud/getting-started-with-node-js-and-bamboo-737183843.html

Answer (score 0):

by

> Just to mention I did not run an npm install On my new environment after deployment since the node modules are all present in my package

Do you mean the file package.json?

It looks like you are missing the node_module files and will need to run `npm install` on your new environment.

This will install all the node_modules listed in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I did not run npm install is because my folder which contains all my changes has the node_modules folder. This was what was deployed . I checked the contents of the folder and all node modules , typing , etc were present. So do I need to run npm install in every environment? Pls let me know

Comment: I see. No, you dont have to run npm install if the packages allready exists, but in your case the error message implies they dont. Maybe they have a different path on your server? how does your include path for system.js in your app look like?

Comment: Also, there could be a problem with different architecture on your server and your local (32bit vs 64bit). Running npm install will avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks @erlend .. it was an issue with the paths. I have corrected it and it seems to be working fine now.